# How to convert dtype of time axis from float32 to datetime64 for multiple files and then merge them in one file?

Tags: python, datetime, time, concatenation, python-xarray

I have separate monthly netcdf files from 1940-2021 and I want to merge them in one single file. But the issue is that the time axis has dtype = float32 and I wonder how to merge them. So I need to convert float32 to datetime64. Please tell me a proper way to handle this problem. And if there is any alternate ways then let me know.

This is a example for how my time axis look for the year 1940 first month:-

```
time (time) float32 1.94e+05

long_name : time: yyyymm

reference_time : 194001.0

standard_name : time 

array([194001.], dtype=float32)
```

Thank you.

Comment: to convert to datetime64 (numpy, pandas), a convenient way is to convert float to int, then use pandas.to_datetime with appropriate parsing directive, e.g. `pd.to_datetime(arr.time.astype(int), format="%Y%m")`.

Comment: "*for multiple files and then merge them in one file*" - now that sounds like multiple questions in one to me. Try to separate the different problems (and questions), that helps you to understand better and keep an overview - and finally it helps getting helpful answers here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks for the help..now I am able to change the format. Could you please tell me that how should I add these changes in the time axis itself i.e within the time axis of a netcdf file?  Actually with the above solution I am able to get separate array. That would be more helpful.

Comment: you should be able to [assing the new coords](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign_coords.html)